# Search for multiple strings in an array with regex

Tags: php, arrays, regex

An input field connects via AJAX to PHP that connects to an API which returns the artist and track name results. See it as a live search functionality. However the API sends bloat that needs to be filtered out.

```
Query:
michael jackson billie jean
```

```
Results:
Michael Jackson - Billie Jean
Michael Jackson - Smooth Criminal
Various artists - Billie Jean
```

The results are stored in a array.

How can I filter out the results that have not all the search words in it? Result 2 en 3 in this case.

I have tried to make use of [preg_grep](https://www.php.net/manual/en/function.preg-grep.php) however it searches for 1 string.

```php
$q = $_GET['q']; //michael jackson billie jean
$strings = explode(' ', $q);

$tracks = [
  "Michael Jackson - Billie Jean",
  "Michael Jackson - Smooth Criminal",
  "Various artists - Billie Jean"
];

$matches = preg_grep('/' . $strings[0] . '/i', $tracks);
```

The basic regex works for the first string. However it needs to match all strings to the array value.
Looping through the tracks array and doing a preg_grep on each item adds many duplicates to the new array.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can dynamically craft a regular expression that contains Positive Lookahead for each word. You can get a feeling of the regular expression here: https://regex101.com/r/Qwjw3N/1

In PHP, it looks something like this:

```
$q = "michael jackson billie jean";
$strings = explode(' ', $q);
$tracks = [
  "Michael Jackson - Billie Jean",
  "Michael Jackson - Smooth Criminal",
  "Various artists - Billie Jean"
];

$regex = '^(?=.*' . implode(')(?=.*', $strings) . ').*$';

$matches = preg_grep('/' .$regex . '/i', $tracks);

var_dump($matches);
```